# matplotlib.pyplot Error "ImportError: cannot import name '_path'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I came across an ImportError in the importing of matplotlib.pyplot on Windows 10 Pro

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\****\Dropbox\Code\Python\lib_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 31, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.artist as martist
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .path import Path
  File "C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import _path, rcParams
ImportError: cannot import name '_path'
```

Here is the script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
plt.plot(squares)
plt.show()
```

If anyone could help me, much appreciated.

Comment: How did you install Python and MPL and on what platform? This is quite confusing? \AppData\Roaming\  ???

Comment: Something went wrong with your matplotlib built.Did you google this error or search for it here on SO? In how far are other answers not helpful?

Comment: @dartdog Windows 10

Comment: The 1st part of the question was how did you do the install??.. You have something very non-standard in the way you have installed,, I'd suggest starting over with Anaconda

Comment: @dartdog I used the command: `python -mpip install -U matplotlib` on Command Prompt

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is wasn't the fact that the other questions were bad on Stack Overflow, it was just that they had no answer at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be a problem related to matplotlib version. I had the same problem and solved it uninstalling the existing version of matplotlib (in my case with ***conda*** but the command is similar substituing ***pip*** to ***conda***) so:
firstly uninstalling with:

```
conda uninstall matplotlib (or pip uninstall matplotlib)
```

and after the successful removal of the existing version (mine was 2.2.2), the following command installed a successive version, that can be specified with '==' after the module name:

```
 conda install matplotlib==3.0.2 (or pip install matplotlib==3.0.2)
```

and the error disappears. 
The uninstall command removed also ***seaborn*** installation so it was necessary to install it after matplotlib but it was easy...
Yeah!:)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're probably like me and doing a lot of `installing/importing`, it can be just a mishap in the original `matplotlib` install... so try doing the ol' get out, walk around to the back side and give it a kick...

```
conda uninstall matplotlib
#let it do its thing

conda install matplotlib
#let it do its thing
```

Then test it on the code you're trying to do and see if it works.  In my case, it came down to a `"_Path"` issue in my original install that messed up things.  After the `uninstall/install`, I was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno what mpip is,, or why,, try plain old pip (or in your case perhaps pip3 ? This may have more to do with how the base Python was installed though,, why I suggest using Anaconda to install all (which automatically installs MPL as well..)